# Adobe Acrobat Pro DC form textfield background gray color not going away

Tags: forms, pdf, adobe, textfield, acrobat

I have a form field text-field and I have set its fill color to no color, but it still shows background gray-ish color in the preview and also after saving the file. I want transparent/white background for the textfield so that reading the text in it can be easy. 
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Can you post the PDF?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit-Preferences-Forms and deselect "show border hover color for fields".